# Not sure how to retrieve some variables only in Parcelable object Arraylist using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've seen so many reference to solve this problem and I just found how to retrieve all variable in object. It works well, but what I want is just showing some variables in detail layout (activity : AboutApp.kt) based on item I clicked. In this case, I don't know how to retrieve the variable name only.
I've tried 3 ways here, but each solution always gives me error.

Solution 1 : The error is name (unresolved reference), I don't know how to call the variable name

```
        val herbalName = this.intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>("extra_item")
        val line1: String = herbalName.name
        val textView1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_name)
        textView1.text = line1
```

Solution 2 : The error in getParcelableExtra

```
        val list = this.intent.getParcelableExtra("extra_item")
        val line1 = list.name
        val textView1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_name)
        textView1.text = line1
```

Solution 3 : It's right but every item that I clicked just show all data in index I write (0 as example), meanwhile I wanna retrieve some elements/variable only and show the data in detail activity based on clicked item in listView

```
        val listData: ArrayList<Herbal> = this.intent.extras!!.getParcelableArrayList("extra_item")!!
        val line1 = listData[0]
        val textView1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_name)
        textView1.text = line1.toString()
```

I've written the Parcelable in data class Herbal, but here is my ArrayList in object HerbalData.

```
val listData: ArrayList<Herbal>
        get() {
            val list = arrayListOf<Herbal>()
            for (position in herbalName.indices) {
                val herbal = Herbal()
                herbal.name = herbalName[position]
                herbal.detail = herbalDetail[position]
                herbal.photo = herbalImage[position]
                list.add(herbal)
            }
            return list
        }
```

I just want to retrieve the name. I'm very grateful for any help. I've spend many times to solve it. Thank you so much.

Comment: first and foremost array list doesn't have name property, Returned value is not `Herbal` it is ArrayList<Parcelable>

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Get it like this: `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Herbal>("extra_item")` and select the element by indexing.

Comment: val herbalName = this.intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Herbal>("extra_item")
        val line1: String = herbalName[0] You mean like this?

Comment: If it's yes, so what's the different between the solution 3? I've tried it but it shows all data. Am I wrong about what you think in ur comment? Sorry, I'm new in android

Comment: yep just call name in that `herbalName[0].name`

Comment: It works, thank you so much. May God bless u always. I'm so sorry, one more trouble, it's not based on item that I clicked. So every item in list view when I clicked, it just show the name by index 0? What should I check?

Comment: put what is selected instead of 0, position should come from where you attached the listener.

Comment: Do you mean that I should make a new function to retrieve the position in this activity or just connect with the adapter activity where onClickListener I write?